# Template Variations title not showing

Tags: python, django

I have made a variation to an Item class in models.py and I think i got the template syntax right but apparently there are something wrong which i can't figure it out

Here is the model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to='approved designs')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('title', 'slug')

class Variation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and here is the template

```
                        {% if item.variation_set.all %}
                        <select class='form-control' name='size'>
                            {% for items in item.variation_set.all %}
                            <option value='{item.variation|lower}'>{{title.title|capfirst}}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                        {% endif %}
```

Comment: What errors are you  getting?

Comment: I think you want to print ```{{items.title|capfirst}}``` instead, right?

Comment: I am not getting errors they are simply not showing the variations, I add variation as sizes small medium and large which is not appearing

Comment: try `items.title` with the 's'

Comment: @Hozayfa El Rifai I tried this but it is showing the items (t-shirt 1 and t-shirt 2) not the variations, what i want it to print is the sizes (Small medium, large)

Comment: @Java_Man thank you both you are both correct it works now

Comment: @Hozayfa El Rifai thank you both you are both correct it works now

Comment: @AhmedKhairy happy coding

Comment: Added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to try `items.title` with the 's'